# I am not able to upload images using react native expo image picker library

Tags: react-native, file-upload, expo, fetch, imagepicker

I am trying to upload a image using expo image picker and upload it using an API. I am using fetch. I am new to react native please help.
I upgraded my code and it was working perfectly before.
Now i get some error.
I was getting syntax error for json but i fixed it.
I cannot figure out how to send the image file

This is my image picker code

```
const pickImageAsync = async type => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
      // allowsMultipleSelection: true,
    });
    console.log('result', result);
    if (!result.canceled) {
      if (type === 'picture') {
        var x = pictureFiles;
        result.assets.forEach(element => {
          x.push(element);
        });
 
        setPictureFiles(x);
      }
      if (type === 'panorama') {
        var x = panoramaFiles;
        result.assets.forEach(element => {
          x.push(element);
        });
        setPanoramaFiles(x);
      }
      // console.log(pictureFiles);
    } else {
      alert('You did not select any image.');
    }
  };
```

This is my Api call

```
const onSubmit = data => {
    setLoading(true);
    data.agent_id = userData.agent_id;
    data.virtualtourservice = isvirtualtourservice ? 1 : 0;
    data.flyerservice = isflyerservice ? 1 : 0;
    data.videoservice = isvideoservice ? 1 : 0;
    const formdt = new FormData();
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => formdt.append(key, data[key]));
    for (let file of pictureFiles) {
      var fname = file.uri.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
      var obj = {
        uri: file.uri,
        name: fname,
        type: file.type,
      };
      formdt.append('picture[]', obj);
    }
    for (let file of videoFiles) {
      var fname = file.path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
      var obj = {
        uri: file.uri,
        name: fname,
        type: file.type,
      };
      formdt.append('video[]', obj);
    }
    for (let file of panoramaFiles) {
      var fname = file.path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
      var obj = {
        uri: file.uri,
        name: fname,
        type: file.type,
      };
      formdt.append('panorama[]', obj);
    }
    formdt.append('authenticate_key', 'abcd123XYZ');
    fileUploadMethod('agent-save-imageset', formdt)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.length > 0) {
          if (res[0].response.status === 'error') {
            ToastAndroid.show(res[0].response.message, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
          } else {
            ToastAndroid.show(res[0].response.message, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            setLoading(false);
            resetControls();
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

The form submits if there are no images or videos.

I think i should use local uri instead of uri.